# Fetch as Google 'Internal Error'

Tags: android, cordova

I developed a cross-platform application using Cordova in Visual Studio 2013. I followed this [steps](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test#top) for providing deep-links in the application, and everything is working fine when testing with the deep linking testing tool (after scanning the code and opening the provided URL, the application is opened exactly on the screen it should, and everything is OK). But when I try to use Fetch as Google from Search Console, I always get the following error:

Internal error

```
The page could not be fetched due to an internal Google error.
Fetched URI: android-app://com.app-name/http/hu
Date: 9/10/15 12:51 AM
Language: English
Googlebot type: Google for android apps
```

I read about Internal error that `android:minSdkVersion must be at least 17` (in my AndroidManifest.xml is 10) or that my app is unable to run on x86 hardware (which I have no idea how to test or what should I modify).

Can anybody help me with this?